# How to add rel="nofollow" attribute to external links in PageDown.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, markdown, pagedown

I'm using [PageDown.js](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pagedown/wikis/PageDown.wiki) to make raw HTML in markdown style like StackOverflow does. My code looks like the following in nodejs:

```
var saneConv require('./pagedown/Markdown.Sanitizer'),
    resultHTML = saneConv.makeHtml('[raw html string]');
```

Now I need to add `rel="nofollow"` to all external links. Unfortunately I can't see that ability in PageDown itself.

Could you advice me please a solution to add `ref="nofollow"` attribute to all external links?

Comment: It makes little sense to add `ref="nofollow"` on client side using JS. This attribute is for webbots which parse your html and do not run scripts. Human visitors cannot see any difference.

Comment: We can't add `ref="nofollow"` on client-side because webbots don't evaluate JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

If all links are external then you could simply use

```
resultHTML = resultHTML.replace('<a ', '<a rel="nofollow" ');
```

or there's a function called *writeAnchorTag* in Markdown.Converter.js that you can change to do what you need.

**Update**

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var fs = require("fs");
var jquery = fs.readFileSync("./path/to/jquery.js", "utf-8");

var saneConv = require('./pagedown/Markdown.Sanitizer'),
    resultHTML = saneConv.makeHtml('[raw html string]');

jsdom.env(resultHTML, [jquery], function(err, window) {
    var $ = window.$;

    $("a").each(function() {
        var $a = $(this);
        var href = $a.attr('href');

        // figure out if href is external or internal
        // let's say if href doesn't contain specific domain it's external so add rel=nofollow
        if (href.indexOf('example.com') < 0 || href.indexOf('example2.com') < 0) {
            // it's external, let's add rel=nofollow
            $a.attr('rel', 'nofollow');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Unfortunately not all links may be external so I need to check this case and make desition to either add `rel="nofollow"`or not. Is there any hooks or any approaches to achieve it without modifying sorce code of pagedown?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any hooks. If all external links start with *http* then you could try `...replace('href="http', 'rel="nofollow" href="http');`

Comment: Hmm. interesting. So all my internal links should starts with `/` but all external ones with http or https?

Comment: Yes that should work. Your internal links simply cannot start with http, that's all.

Comment: This is interesting sollusion but I have subdomain also. So If I need to add link from subdomain to main domain your solution will not work :(

Comment: The easiest would be to change the writeAnchorTag function.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But maybe I can use some available hook to change my links? All I need is just `.replace` within some text. PageDown has set of hooks like https://code.google.com/archive/p/pagedown/wikis/PageDown.wik `Plugin hooks` section. So, what do you thing about it?

Comment: I couldn't find any suitable hook. Have you considered using different markdown parser? There are many and i think better ones like *marked* https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked

Comment: I'm using pagedown becasue it uses stackoverflow. I need to have the same widget, so I have to use pagedown

Comment: Sorry, I got you broken link to pagedown wiki. Here is correct https://code.google.com/archive/p/pagedown/wikis/PageDown.wiki

Comment: I figured that out :) it's on github too https://github.com/ujifgc/pagedown I don't think i can help you anymore i've run out of ideas. Maybe one more If this was in browser(although you can use jQuery in node too) i would probably use jQuery to find all anchors and then i would check the *href* attribute whether it's external or internal link. Well i'm not good at regex that's why i would use jQuery :)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use client-side solution because `ref="follows"` belong to Web crawlers so I can use server-side solusion only.

Comment: I added example, just in case. I didn't tried the code tho.